# A "standard" Windows folder that is readable only by administrators

Tags: windows, administrator, environment-variables

Is there a folder on Windows that always exists (like a user home or ProgramData), but it can be modified and **read** only by Administrators?

So far, the best candidate I found is the %APPDATA% of the "Local System" account that seems to exist always. But it's real location depends on the Windows version and if it is running as a 32-bit or a 64-bit application.

- C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Application Data
- C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming

There is also a chance that in the future it may even migrate somewhere under

- C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService

And it may not be that easy to find this location if a software is running under another Administrator's account and not as "Local System" (a Service).

Is there maybe a better alternative to %APPDATA% of the "Local System" that I am missing?

Or is there a simple and reliable way of getting %APPDATA% of the "Local System" account by any other Administrator user?

Comment: Is there a reason you must use an existing folder, instead of creating and configuring one of your own?

Comment: Well, we will create our subfolder in the existing one. So we need an existing folder, as the starting point. I do not like an idea to put one on the c:\ drive, for example. But, we could still use ProgramData and make our subfolder not readable by non-Admin users during the installation. That maybe a way to go, eventually...

Comment: Yes, if you're writing your own program, creating your own folder is _definitely_ the way to go. Don't litter system locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If I understand correctly, you're looking for locations that can be read only by Administrators and where Administrators can also write. Here's a list of folders having these characteristics that are present both in both my Windows 10 and Windows 7 installations. Anyway, creating your own folder under ProgramData as per your comment sounds like a sane idea.

```
C:\MSOCache
C:\PerfLogs
C:\Windows\Temp
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\PCPKSP\WindowsAIK
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Downloader
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Provisioning
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Temp
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\LfSvc
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Power Efficiency Diagnostics
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\wfp
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows NT\MSFax
C:\ProgramData\USOPrivate
C:\Recovery
C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs
C:\Windows\AUInstallAgent
C:\Windows\LiveKernelReports
C:\Windows\Logs\HomeGroup
C:\Windows\Logs\SystemRestore
C:\Windows\Logs\Telephony
C:\Windows\ModemLogs
C:\Windows\PLA\Reports
C:\Windows\PLA\Rules
C:\Windows\PLA\Templates
C:\Windows\Prefetch
C:\Windows\security\audit
C:\Windows\security\cap
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService
C:\Windows\System32\appmgmt\MACHINE
C:\Windows\System32\Com\dmp
C:\Windows\System32\config
C:\Windows\System32\Configuration
C:\Windows\System32\ias
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Fax\Incoming
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Fax\Outgoing
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI
C:\Windows\System32\MsDtc
C:\Windows\System32\networklist
C:\Windows\System32\SleepStudy
C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS
C:\Windows\System32\spool\SERVERS
C:\Windows\System32\sru
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks_Migrated
C:\Windows\System32\wbem\MOF
C:\Windows\System32\WDI
C:\Windows\System32\wfp
```

Comment: If I cannot accept a comment as an answer, I will accept this one. There are obviously already subfolders in the ProgramData that are "admins only". So putting your data there and changing the permissions are the way to go.

Comment: You can ask "commmentators" to transform their comments into an answer (i.e. create an answer), then you can accept it. P.S. I wish those who downvote would leave a comment stating the reason: that would be a more constructive approach.